# Issues when converting a multipage PDF to a single image and applying background color

Tags: php, pdf, imagick

I tried to convert a multipage PDF to a single image. As there are transparent regions inside, I have to set the background color.

1st approach:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: image/png");
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$img1 = new Imagick();
$img1->setBackgroundColor('red');
$img1->readImage($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/pdf/Anschreiben-Brigitte.pdf');
$img1->setImage($img1->mergeImageLayers(imagick::LAYERMETHOD_FLATTEN));
$img1->resetIterator();
$imgOut = $img1->appendImages(true);
$imgOut->setImageFormat("png");
echo $imgOut->getimagesblob();
```

Unfortunately this applies the background color to the first page only

2nd approach:
I read this thread:
[php Imagemagick jpg black background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099644/php-imagemagick-jpg-black-background)
where Aron Mason is posting that Imagick is iterable.
I tried this code:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: image/png");
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$img1 = new Imagick();
$img1->readImage($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/pdf/Anschreiben-Brigitte.pdf');
foreach ($img1 as $c => $page) {
    $page->setBackgroundColor('red');
    $page->setImage($page->mergeImageLayers(imagick::LAYERMETHOD_FLATTEN));
}
$img1->resetIterator();
$imgOut = $img1->appendImages(true);
$imgOut->setImageFormat("png");
echo $imgOut->getimagesblob();
```

Unfortunately the page crashes, loads and loads and doesn't come to an end.

3rd approach:
I suspected that Imagick does not like it when the page is modified inside the foreach loop.
Therefore I modified the code like this:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: image/png");
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$img1 = new Imagick();
$img1->readImage($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/pdf/Anschreiben-Brigitte.pdf');
$img2 = new Imagick();
foreach ($img1 as $c => $page) {
    $pg = new Imagick();
    $pg->setBackgroundColor('red');
    $pg->addImage((clone $page)->mergeImageLayers(imagick::LAYERMETHOD_FLATTEN));
    $img2->addImage($pg);
    $pg->destroy();
}
$img2->resetIterator();
$imgOut = $img2->appendImages(true);
$imgOut->setImageFormat("png");
echo $imgOut->getimagesblob();
```

This runs but unfortunately on each page all pages are stacked one above the other.

4th approach:
I ended up in this code:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: image/png");
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$img1 = new Imagick();
$img1->readImage($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/pdf/Anschreiben-Brigitte.pdf');
$img2 = new Imagick();
foreach ($img1 as $c => $page) {
    $pg = new Imagick();
    $pg->setBackgroundColor('red');
    $pg->readImage($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/pdf/Anschreiben-Brigitte.pdf[' . $c . ']');
    $pg->setImage($pg->mergeImageLayers(imagick::LAYERMETHOD_FLATTEN));
    $img2->addImage($pg);
}
$img2->resetIterator();
$imgOut = $img2->appendImages(true);
$imgOut->setImageFormat("png");
echo $imgOut->getimagesblob();
```

This is working fine however it's anything but straight forward.

Explanations why my initial approaches are running into issues are welcome.
And hints how to implement a code that is more straight forward.

If this cannot be reproduced with any multipage PDF I will provide a sample.

Version of Imagick: 7.1.0-18 Q16 x64 2021-12-14
Ghostscript installed yesterday, thus should be the latest version.